# Flutter: keyboard pops out when opening drawer

Tags: flutter

everyone
I'm encountering a problem while using Flutter.
Basically when i open my CustomDrawer widget, not always but quite frequently, the keyboard pops out in an unwanted way.

I don't get why it does it... maybe because it re-runs the build method or something i don't know. Down below you can find the code.

Every little bit of information is well appreciated.

Thanks everyone.

Here's the Screen.dart

```js
...

build(context) {

    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      drawer: CustomDrawer(),

...
```

And the custom_drawer_widget.dart

```js
...
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: Text(
                  "Hi, $username",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 22,
                  ),
                ),
                alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                color: Colors.yellow,
                height: 300,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Container(
            height: 60.0 * 6,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 60,
                  child: FlatButton(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 10),
                    highlightColor: Colors.grey[350],
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.home,
                          color: Colors.grey[600],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 30),
                        Text("Homepage"),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.book),
                    title: Text("Diary"),
                    onTap: () {}),
                ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.chat),
                    title: Text("Chat"),
                    onTap: () {}),
                ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.credit_card),
                    title: Text("Credit Card"),
                    onTap: () {}),
                ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
                    title: Text("Sign Out"),
                    onTap: () async {
                      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
                    }),
                ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.settings),
                    title: Text("Settings"),
                    onTap: () {}),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(22),
              alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Text("Version 0.1"),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
...
```

Answer (score 8):

I don't see exactly where you dismiss the keyboard, but I was having the same issue after dismissing the keyboard after a form submit. This fixed my issue.

See this answer here:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/54277

Where instead of:

```
      onTap: () {
        FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
        if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
          currentFocus.unfocus();
        }
      },
```

The code should be:

```
      onTap: () {
        final FocusScopeNode currentScope = FocusScope.of(context);
        if (!currentScope.hasPrimaryFocus && currentScope.hasFocus) {
          FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus.unfocus();
        }
      },
```

Comment: Works for me..Thanks :)